# Is there any difference between "send something to someone" and "send something over to someone"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me what if there is any difference between *send something to someone* and *send something over to someone*? For example:

> Can you please **send** those files **to** me by Friday?
>
> Can you please **send** those files **over** **to** me by Friday?

I've consulted many dictionaries, such as [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/send+over) but I couldn't find the answer. In a lot cases dictionaries don't explain subtle differences, such as in this case, so I would appreciate it if you share your thoughts on this one.

Comment: What do you think? Have you looked into it at all?

Comment: Yes, I've looked into it. And if you go on the internet, you won't find the difference between the two, I mean I couldn't.

Comment: The requirement to show your research serves several purposes: 1) to eliminate questions that are easily answerable with research, 2) to save those answering the question from repeating the same research you've already done, 3) to reduce back-and-forth like this in the comment section, and 4) to get answerers invested in answering your question because it appears you're doing your due diligence first, and not just asking a question here because it's easier than doing the research yourself.

Comment: So I'm closing the question as off-topic until it includes information about what research you've done, and what thoughts, if any, you have about differences between the two.

Comment: I have included the research I've done, so would you please be kind enough to reopen the question so that the community and me would get some answers.

Comment: I'm happy to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mean almost exactly the same thing. I've come up with a couple minor nuances.

With "over to me", it sounds more familiar and casual, where with just "to me" it's neutral.

Also, "over to me" mildly suggests that this person is your peer, because you're sending it across, on the same level. It's in contrast with expressions like, "Send that **up** to the CEO/to head office" or "Send that **down** to custodial/to the mail room.